# More google charts on single page

Tags: wordpress, charts, google-visualization, visualization, pygooglechart

i need to show more than 1 chart on single page - this charts should be separate, not in one block. I found some advice here, but i dont know what  wrong in my codes is. Everything worked, until i have change the line " google.charts.load('43', {packages: ['corechart']});" I tried changed the function name, but still doesnt work. I am sorry for my english and i am amateur about codes.

Chart 1

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('43', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chart2);
function chart2() {
var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(
{"containerId":"2C2D","dataTable":{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"","pattern":"","type":"string","p":{}},{"id":"","label":"CZK","pattern":"","type":"number","p":{}},{"id":"","label":"zbývá CZK","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"březen","f":null},{"v":1844,"f":null},{"v":143739,"f":null}]}],"p":null},"options":{"isStacked":true,"animation":{"duration":2500,"startup":true},"bar":{"groupWidth": "25%"},"booleanRole":"certainty","hAxis":{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindow":{"max":150000,"min":null},"minValue":null,"maxValue":160000,"logScale":false,"gridlines":{"count":"4"}},"vAxes":[{"useFormatFromData":true,"minValue":null,"maxValue":null,"viewWindow":null,"viewWindowMode":null},{"useFormatFromData":true}],"legend":"bottom","series":{"1":{"color":"#b7b7b7"}},"fontName":"Georgia","title":"Náklady CZK"},"state":{},"view":{},"isDefaultVisualization":true,"chartType":"BarChart"}
);
wrapper.draw();
};
</script>
<div style='border: 0px darkgray solid;width:500px;'>
<div id='2C2D' style='width:500px; height:200px;'></div>
</div>
```

Chart 2

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('43', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(
{"containerId":"visualizationDCA3","dataTable":{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"","pattern":"","type":"string","p":{}},{"id":"","label":"CZK","pattern":"","type":"number","p":{}},{"id":"","label":"zbývá CZK","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"březen","f":null},{"v":62036,"f":null},{"v":2213460,"f":null}]}],"p":null},"options":{"isStacked":true,"animation":{"duration":2500,"startup":true},"bar":{"groupWidth": "25%"},"booleanRole":"certainty","hAxis":{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindow":{"max":2500000,"min":null},"minValue":null,"maxValue":2500000,"logScale":false},"vAxes":[{"useFormatFromData":true,"minValue":null,"maxValue":null,"viewWindow":null,"viewWindowMode":null},{"useFormatFromData":true}],"legend":"bottom","fontName":"Georgia","title":"Celkový CZK","series":{"1":{"color":"#b7b7b7"}}},"state":{},"view":{},"isDefaultVisualization":true,"chartType":"BarChart"}
);
wrapper.draw();
};
</script>
<div style='border: 0px darkgray solid;width:500px;'>
<div id='visualizationDCA3' style='width:500px; height:200px;'></div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `init` function, then call the other charts from there...

```js
google.charts.load('43', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(init);

function init() {
  drawChart();
  chart2();
}

function drawChart() {
  var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(
    {"containerId":"visualizationDCA3","dataTable":{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"","pattern":"","type":"string","p":{}},{"id":"","label":"CZK","pattern":"","type":"number","p":{}},{"id":"","label":"zbývá CZK","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"brezen","f":null},{"v":62036,"f":null},{"v":2213460,"f":null}]}],"p":null},"options":{"isStacked":true,"animation":{"duration":2500,"startup":true},"bar":{"groupWidth": "25%"},"booleanRole":"certainty","hAxis":{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindow":{"max":2500000,"min":null},"minValue":null,"maxValue":2500000,"logScale":false},"vAxes":[{"useFormatFromData":true,"minValue":null,"maxValue":null,"viewWindow":null,"viewWindowMode":null},{"useFormatFromData":true}],"legend":"bottom","fontName":"Georgia","title":"Celkový CZK","series":{"1":{"color":"#b7b7b7"}}},"state":{},"view":{},"isDefaultVisualization":true,"chartType":"BarChart"}
  );
  wrapper.draw();
};

function chart2() {
  var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(
    {"containerId":"2C2D","dataTable":{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"","pattern":"","type":"string","p":{}},{"id":"","label":"CZK","pattern":"","type":"number","p":{}},{"id":"","label":"zbývá CZK","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"brezen","f":null},{"v":1844,"f":null},{"v":143739,"f":null}]}],"p":null},"options":{"isStacked":true,"animation":{"duration":2500,"startup":true},"bar":{"groupWidth": "25%"},"booleanRole":"certainty","hAxis":{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindow":{"max":150000,"min":null},"minValue":null,"maxValue":160000,"logScale":false,"gridlines":{"count":"4"}},"vAxes":[{"useFormatFromData":true,"minValue":null,"maxValue":null,"viewWindow":null,"viewWindowMode":null},{"useFormatFromData":true}],"legend":"bottom","series":{"1":{"color":"#b7b7b7"}},"fontName":"Georgia","title":"Náklady CZK"},"state":{},"view":{},"isDefaultVisualization":true,"chartType":"BarChart"}
  );
  wrapper.draw();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div style='border: 0px darkgray solid;width:500px;'>
<div id='visualizationDCA3' style='width:500px; height:200px;'></div>

<div style='border: 0px darkgray solid;width:500px;'>
<div id='2C2D' style='width:500px; height:200px;'></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps -- you only need `google.charts.load` and `setOnLoadCallback` once per page...

Comment: Thank you very much, but is there some solution when i need separate code for every chart? Till today i have page as a dashboard (about 5-6 charts) and there i use Page builder in wordpress. On page builder widget i pasted separate code and i can affect where and which chart will be - this is reason why I need solo code for each chart.